# Как настроить QT creator в Mint Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qtcreator, linux-mint

Здравствуйте, нужно для лабораторных писать ПО под Linux. Поставил на Virtual Box Mint(писали что он лучше всего для новичков подойдет). Установил QT Creator, вроде все файлы нужные скачало. Но в итоге всё равно не могу создать проект.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как ты поставил qt creator?

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум нужно установить g++ и/или clang. Qt для разработки тоже не установлен, его удобнее ставить с официального сайта. Если ставить пакетным менеджером - нужно искать, как называются пакеты, соответствующие различным модулям Qt. Если вам нужен только QtCreator, без Qt - тогда в качестве системы сборки можно поставить CMake, или отдельно QMake без остального Qt.

QtCreator обычно подхватывает установленные инструменты сам, нужно только перезапустить его (в некоторых случаях нужно перезапустить систему, но это не про Mint). Но QMake, в отличие от CMake, не умеет работать с компилятором, имя которого отличается от стандартного (например, clang-5.0 вместо clang) - приходится задавать имя компилятора для каждого проекта.

Comment: Скачал g++ и cmake - не помогло